# GtkRevealer glitches the text view drawing

Tags: c, windows, windows-7, gtk, visual-glitch

During the development of my program I came across one drawing glitch that I was unable to solve. I am using GtkRevealer to show and hide a GtkInfoBar above another box holding a scrolled window with a GtkTextView (actually GtkSourceView) a lot like it is in gedit.
The whole thing is packed in a GtkPaned.

When I hide the infobar through the revealer, a black area in the text view appears and it disappears when a redrawing of the widget must occur (for instance when I click on the text view to place the cursor)
Additionally, this glitch does not appear if I enlarge the default resolution of the window, which for compatibility reasons is 640x480.
I understand that this may be hard to reproduce, but I am unaware who encountered the same problem. He maybe knows a workaround to this issue.
Also any idea is welcome.
I will draw exactly how the glitch looks on gedit (although it doesn't happen in gedit or it does but I cannot hit the correct resolution).
[image]

I tried to force a redrawing with `gtk_widget_queue_draw()` but nothing happens and it won't, because it has nothing to redraw.
I will try now to place the cursor automatically. It may work, but it is not functionally adequate.
**EDIT:**
Surprisingly it did not work. Grabbing the focus and placing the cursor
had no effect on the glitched visual behavior. I had to even make a new line
to fix it this time.
The fact that I have to resize the window with a value more than a specific point, may mean that the glitch may be due to alignment miscaulculations, but this doesn't explain why adding new line or a text mark in the gutter that colorizes the entire line also removes the black field.

Answer (score 1):

Currently this bug has been encountered in another programs with a text view as well, but hasn't been reported as a bug yet.
Perhaps this has something to do with the fact that it is hard to reproduce.

I found that hiding the gtk text view with `gtk_widget_hide()` and then showing it with `gtk_widget_show()` works. The flicker of this visual glitch is not noticeable, perhaps due to GTK+ being event-based and waiting for the function to return to process changes.